# Quartz.net: How to create jobs using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net, quartz.net-3.0

I am trying to execute a Quartz scheduler job in .NET with a non-empty constructor and I try to use the default Dependency Injection of .NET to supply the dependencies. This is my job class which needs a dependency injection

```cs
public class MyJob : IJob 
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MyJob(ILogger<MyJob> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));  
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("It's working!");
    }
}
```

And this is how I build the job

```cs
IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>()
    .WithIdentity("MyID", "MyGroup")
    .Build();

var triggerBuilder = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("MyID")
    .StartAt(DateTime.Now)
    .WithCronSchedule("*/1 * * * * ?"); // Every second

var trigger = triggerBuilder.Build();
_scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger)
```

Now, I have defined in my app configuration the following:

```cs
// Quartz configuration.
services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    // Add dependency injection.
    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory(options =>
    {
        // if we don't have the job in DI, allow fallback
        // to configure via default constructor
        options.AllowDefaultConstructor = true;
    });
});

services.AddTransient<MyJob>();
// Also tried services.AddTransient<IJob, MyJob>();
```

as defined in the [documentation on DI](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html#di-aware-job-factories). Yet when I rebuild my solution and run the server, the following error is thrown:

> Quartz.SchedulerException: Problem instantiating class 'MyProject.MyNamespace.Myjob: Cannot instantiate type which has no empty constructor
> Parameter name: MyJob' ---> System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate type which has no empty constructor

Yet, I explicitly setup MS DI for Quartz to use following their documentation. So how can I inject dependencies? I am using Quartz 3.2.4 and I installed the `Quartz.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package (also 3.2.4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register your jobs and triggers within the `AddQuartz`. If you look at the [official documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html) you will see that the `ScheduleJob`/`AddJob`/`AddTrigger` calls are done within the callback which ensures that the DI works. This will probably change in 3.3 version and the job registration won't be that strict anymore.

Comment: How do you know that it will be updated in version 3.3?

Comment: [This PR](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/pull/1127) changed the job instantiation to happen without resolving from the container. Triggers still need to be inside `AddQuartz()` if you want them to be registered against the configured scheduler (you can resolve the scheduler and then add triggers of course).